# Do these two approaches of await future in dart, return the same thing

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

```
var id;

Future load() async {
  
    //Approach #1
    id = await getUserId();

    //Approach #2
    await getUserId().then((id) {

        setState((){
            id = id;
        });

    });


}
```

If there is any difference in the two approaches I took, I would be happy to know :)

Comment: Other than calling `setState`, these are identical. Be aware however that `id = id;` is likely not doing what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use `async/await`, you should use the `async` keyword in every method that relies upon asynchronous data; just like in JavaScript. In any case, it's better to properly loose couple your code, in a way that a function depends only on its own context, and is used without accessing to other scopes.

Therefore, the first example should be such as:

```
var id;
Future load() async {
    
    // you should put the "await" when you consume "load()", rather than here.
    return getUserId();

}
```

Have in mind that this is a blocking operation, which often is nice, but sometimes you may need a more asynchronous approach. Per example, when you want to load different stuff and you don't really care about when the responses arrive. Then, the second example is fine to use like this in the method you desire:

```
    var id;
    // here you don't need await at all.
    getUserId().then((id) {

       setState((){
         id = id;
       }
    });

}
```

This second example will not fire the `.then()` anonymous function until the request has finished, which permits the program to do more stuff while it loads. Sometimes that's a perk, sometimes that's a problem.

Use the first when you depend on that data, use the second for assets that you don't immediatly need.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, and otherwise loved your answer... If I am calling the load() future on the initState, how can I wait until it loads, before building the actual page? That's where I am facing a problem.

Comment: @MarcoSoares Use a `FutureBuilder`. You can't/shouldn't prevent a widget from building while waiting for a `Future`. You should be showing something else like a loading widget until the `Future` completes.